# VBA Calculating Total Weekdays using Networkdays.Intl

Tags: vba, excel

How I'm possible to calculate total of weekdays between two dates using Networkdays.Intl?

Currently here is my code :

```
.Cells(lrow, "AH").Value = Abs(WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(.Cells(lrow, "AD"), .Cells(lrow, "T"), 1))
```

I'm trying to make the "=" symbol with <> but seems error. Can it be done or theres another way?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You got confused with writing a formula in a cell for get the value and calling a worksheet function in VBA and just output the result in the cell.

**Edit1:** You usually subtract the result by 1 to get the correct count of weekdays in between dates.

For the first option, try:

```
.Cells(lrow, "AH").Formula = "=ABS(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(" & .Cells(lrow, "AD").Address _
                             & "," & .Cells(lrow, "T").Address & ",1))-1"
```

Above will write the formula on the cell.

For the second option:

```
.Cells(lrow, "AH").Value = Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl( _
                           .Cells(lrow, "AD"), .Cells(lrow, "T"), 1)) - 1
```

Comment: Actually, my coding has no error. The result produce between my coding and yours were same. Currently I just want the total of Weekdays between two dates, not total of Workdays.

Comment: @IlhamideaZ Ah I misunderstood when you said it errors. But that is suppose to return what you want.

Comment: @IlhamideaZ By does not work, what do you mean? You usually subtract the result of that function by 1 to get the actual count.

Comment: It give Total of Workdays. But what I need is Total of Weekdays.

Comment: @IlhamideaZ Might as well give a sample data and sample result.